# Overriding Enum#toString not desirable?

Tags: java, enums

I just noticed that the [`Enum#toString` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29) states (emphasis mine):

> Returns the name of this enum constant, as contained in the declaration. **This method may be overridden, though it typically isn't** necessary or **desirable**. An enum type should override this method when a more "programmer-friendly" string form exists.

By default, `toString()` and [`name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) return the same thing, so even once `toString` has been overriden, one can still access the name of the enum through the `name()` method.

Does anybody know why overriding `Enum#toString` would not be desirable?

EDIT: For reference, `name()`'s javadoc (emphasis as in the original):

> Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration. **Most programmers should use the toString() method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name**. This method is designed primarily for use in specialized situations where correctness depends on getting the exact name, which will not vary from release to release.

Comment: One example of when it might be desirable could be when there's an existing coding convention that enum values should be named in all caps (e.g., `VALUE`), but that would look clunky to a user, so `toString` could be implemented to return `name.toLowerCase()` or some other case manipulation.

Comment: My use case is that the enum represents a set of options displayed to the user (e.g. in a `JComboBox`). My first inclination was to override `toString` to provide a localized display name for the user, but the javadoc suggested only overriding to get a better "programmer-friendly" string form which lead me to believe it wasn't appropriate for use as a "user-friendly" form. However, the comment in the javadoc for `name()` suggests that `toString()` is designed to return a *user*-friendly name which leads me to believe that the javadoc for `toString` should same "user-friendly" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is simply some confusion regarding the meaning of the word "desirable" here. The javadoc basically says the same thing twice: overriding toString() is generally not required for the enum to work and it's therefore not useful (desirable) to do so.

So to answer your question: it would **not** be desirable to override toString() if: A) you know that you'll never have to display a string representation of the enum's name, or B) the default string representation suffices to identify the enum should this be required.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker - I thought not desirable meant "should be avoided". Your explanation would make sense.

Comment: Yes, I think to make it more clear, you could replace "desirable" with the word "recommended".

Answer (score 3):

With an enum, you have a specific set of constant values.  When the `toString` method is called for that enum, one would typically expect the name to be returned, so overwriting the `toString` method would return somewhat unexpected results.

Comment: Right. when they say it isn't desirable, they probably don't mean "you really shouldn't do this," but instead "stop and think for a second whether you really have a good reason to." It all comes down to providing clients with the least confusing behavior.

Comment: If I really want to get the name of the enum value as it is declared, I call name, not toString.

Comment: Yeah, you can do either, but as toString defaults to name, most would expect name to be the return value... especially since the whole point of an enum is to have a set of constant values.  By calling name directly, you are ensuring you get the expected result.  You could certainly overwrite toString if you need alternate formatting or whatever.

Comment: It's nice, though, to be able to pass an enum value directly to println and have it automatically converted into a string representation (via toString).

Answer (score 2):

If your enums are more complex than just their names, e.g. if they contain private fields, `toSting()` could be overridden to print these and give a better explanation of the enum field than just its' name.

Comment: My question is the opposite: why could it be undesirable to do what you describe?

Comment: Well since the documentation says that it **typically** isn't neccesary or desirable I take it that unless you have a "complex" structure in your enum, it is not neccesary. I don't get the feeling that the author of the documentation says "You should not override, it is a bad idea"